# Simulate Click event using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, click, simulate

I am scraping some data from this link
 https://www.vbgov.com/property-search#DetailView=14760123360000. But i am unable to simulate click event on "Sales History & Tax Information" tab using webdriver Selenium and python.

```
driver.get("https://www.vbgov.com/property-search#")

searchBox1 = driver.find_element_by_id("consolidated-search-query")

searchBox1.send_keys("1124 LUKE DR")

searchBox1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="property"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')

link.click()

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="property-counts"]/h4')

tab = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Sales History & Tax Information")
tab.click()
```

Comment: What error are you seeing, if any? Is `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` raising an error? Is `click()`? Or is it simply that nothing appears to happen in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to click on the 'Sales History & Tax Information tab' and its happening too , but it is happening while the page loads and after page load by default it is navigate to 'land/Building Information' tab. So here i am waiting for page to load before clicking on 'Sales History & Tax Information tab' by waiting till 'property blue prints' loads.

Using time.sleep before clicking 'Sales History & Tax Information tab' also works here but not preferable.

```
searchBox1 = driver.find_element_by_id("consolidated-search-query")
searchBox1.send_keys("1124 LUKE DR")
searchBox1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="property"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
link.click()
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="property-counts"]/h4')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Land Information']")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='band visible ready']")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Sales History & Tax Information']"))).click()
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To simulate click event on *Sales History & Tax Information* tab, you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='navbar nav-pills nav hasOverflow']//li[@role='tab']/a").click()
```

Comment: is `<selenium element>.click()` superior in any form to executing javascript, like `driver.execute_script(document.querySelector(...).click())`?