# Selenium Python - javascript function call

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

how can i call a javascript function in Selenium Python?

I'm trying to click on a button like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btndefault j-open-game j-gamingButton" data-gameid="1280" data-productid="2" ...>
```

But if i search it with:

```
btn = browser.find_element_by_class_name('btndefault j-open-game j-gamingButton')
```

I receive:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btndefault j-open-game j-gamingButton"}
```

if i search it with:

```
btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='j-gamingButton']")
```

I receive:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@name='j-gamingButton']"}
```

if i search it with:

```
btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='j-btndefault j-open-game j-gamingButton']")
```

I receive:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@name='j-btndefault j-open-game j-gamingButton']"}
```

if i search it with:

```
btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='j-btndefault j-open-game j-gamingButton']")
```

I receive:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Do you have any suggestions for me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732196/simulate-click-event-using-selenium-in-python

Comment: Is it possible you're looking for elements in the wrong context?  for instance are these elements in an iframe?